# Codility's count passing cars in opposite directions in C#

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, programming-challenge, array

I programmed a few things in java and now I'm learning C#. I've been doing exercises from Codility.

The first 3 or 4 were very difficult to me but now I guess I've got the hang of it. This site helped a lot at improving my style and the things I now think I should be looking at before contenting myself with the final code. I comment a lot less than previous posts because I guess the names and the constants are self explanatory.

- Are there still things to improve in my code in easy exercises like this?

Task score: 100%

Detected time complexity: $O(N)\$

> ***Task description***
>
> ---
>
> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. The consecutive
>   elements of array A represent consecutive cars on a road.
>
> Array A contains only 0s and/or 1s:
>
> 0 represents a car traveling east, 1 represents a car traveling west.
>   The goal is to count passing cars. We say that a pair of cars (P, Q),
>   where 0 ≤ P < Q < N, is passing when P is traveling to the east and Q
>   is traveling to the west.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 0
>   A[1] = 1
>   A[2] = 0
>   A[3] = 1
>   A[4] = 1 
>   We have five
>   pairs of passing cars: (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4).
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given a non-empty array A of N integers, returns the number of
>   pairs of passing cars.
>
> The function should return −1 if the number of pairs of passing cars
>   exceeds 1,000,000,000.
>
> For example, given:
>
> A[0] = 0
>   A[1] = 1
>   A[2] = 0
>   A[3] = 1
>   A[4] = 1 
>   the function should return 5, as explained above.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.

And this is my solution, please note that if 1000000000+ passing cars are counted, then the return value of the function should be -1. I had to check for overflows, because one of the tests returned a huge negative number if overflowing, also if overflow occurs before 1000000000 (I don't know if an int holds that number), then it would stop counting sooner, hence than try/catch block improves performance(?).

```
public static int GetNumberOfPassingCars( int[] passingCars )
{
    const int OVERFLOW = -1 ;
    const int EAST = 0 ;
    const int WEST = 1 ;
    int carTravelingEast = 0, pairOfPassingCars = 0;
    foreach( var passingCar in passingCars )
    {
        if ( passingCar == EAST )
        {
            ++carTravelingEast;
        }
        else if ( passingCar == WEST )
        { 
            try
            {
                pairOfPassingCars = checked( pairOfPassingCars + carTravelingEast );
                if ( pairOfPassingCars > 1000000000 )
                {
                    return OVERFLOW;
                }
            }
            catch( OverflowException )
            {
                return OVERFLOW;
            }
        }
    }
    return pairOfPassingCars;
}
```

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overflow averted

Performance of your algorithm is optimal since you iterate the input just once in \$O(n)\$ time complexity. There is a way to avoid the `checked` overflow guard. Noone forces you to use `int` to perform the arithmetic in the method body.

> ```
> int carTravelingEast = 0, pairOfPassingCars = 0;
> ```

Using `uint` with a max value of \$4,294,967,295\$ would never overflow, since:

- `carTravelingEast` can never be more than `int`'s max value \$2,147,483,647\$ (because of the length of an array is capped)
- the maximum value \$3,147,483,647\$  as the sum of the custom threshold of one billion + int's max value could never exceed uint's max value (and we exit early on reaching one billion)

### Code Conventions

- Don't use UPPERCASE variable names for constants; use PascalCase instead.
- Use white space according to [Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions).

  - `GetNumberOfPassingCars( int[] passingCars )` -> `GetNumberOfPassingCars(int[] passingCars)`
  - `foreach( var passingCar in passingCars )` -> `foreach (var passingCar in passingCars)`
- Use plural name for a variable that represents multiple objects: `pairOfPassingCars` -> `pairsOfPassingCars`.
- Use a constant to avoid magic numbers; `const uint maxLimit = 1000000000;`.
- Throw `ArgumentNullException` when mandatory arguments are null in public methods.

---

### Code Refactored

```
public static int GetNumberOfPassingCars(int[] passingCars)
{
    if (passingCars == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(passingCars));

    const int Overflow = -1;
    const int East = 0;
    const int West = 1;
    const uint maxLimit = 1000000000;
    uint carsTravelingEast = 0, pairsOfPassingCars = 0;

    foreach (var passingCar in passingCars)
    {
        if (passingCar == East)
        {
            ++carsTravelingEast;
        }
        else if (passingCar == West)
        { 
            pairsOfPassingCars += carsTravelingEast;
            if (pairsOfPassingCars > maxLimit)
            {
                return Overflow;
            }
        }
    }

    return (int)pairsOfPassingCars;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments. So thanks for that, although codility's compiler throws the following error:
"Solution.cs(32,16): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `uint' to `int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
After that, adding the cast (int), does pass the tests with 100% final score. The other thing I don't get is why would you throw an ArgumentNullException when just returning that 0 pairsOfPassingCars have been found is OK, and the foreach wouldn't even have to iterate through an empty array? so, no improvement in performance, nor result. Thanks again.

Comment: I was editing (I'm new so I forget about pressing Shift+Enter, when trying to nbsp). 
Not an important error at all! And of course, I like another point of view (otherwise, why posting here?), and tool for handling overflows :-) 
If there's another way of doing it (according to the uint part), then I totally get it. My question is, is that way better? I mean you say I can avoid Checked... should I? and why?
And the ArgumentNullException I think is unneeded in this context, even though if in general it's a good practice I should follow, then I get it too.

Comment: I'm sticking to this version of the code. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It did. Considering the fact that overflow checking was unnecessary, made me realize code was perfectly fine without it when I moved `if ( pairOfPassingCars > 1000000000 )  {  return OVERFLOW; }` up. It used to be at the bottom, and returned OVERFLOW if that was true, or pairsOfPassingCars otherwise... That's what made me check